# What exactly is there in the /etc/passwd file?

Tags: linux, unix

Well we all know that it holds passwords. But cat-ing it gives out nothing. Not even encrypted gibberish. So how exactly is a password stored in this? Is this like a device file or something?

Comment: Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_password

Comment: Catting it seems to give me a whole bunch of output.

Comment: Belongs to superuser or serverfault!

Answer (score 7):

For a little historical background:

Long ago, there was the /etc/passwd file that held all sorts of information about the user, including not only an encrypted version of the user's password, but things like the user's home directory, groups, default shell, and name.  This was handy, and lots of system utilities used the /etc/passwd file for various purposes.  The practice of storing only an encrypted version of the password was a great advance over storing the real password in a (hopefully) protected file, and the encryption algorithm could be tuned to be fast enough to be practical but slow enough to make brute force cracking impractical with contemporary hardware.

Back then, Unix was usually used in research and academic environments, and security wasn't a big deal (which turned out to be a bad idea in 1988, with the [Robert Morris worm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm)).  As it was used in more hostile environments, and as computer power improved, it was less and less practical to rely on encryption alone, and so it became desirable to move the passwords to a less accessible file.

Now, there were very large numbers of programs of varying sorts that used /etc/passwd for the information buried there, and it was not practical to go through and change them all.  Therefore, the passwords were put into a new file (often /etc/shadow), which was locked down as much as possible to all accounts except root, and all the other information was left behind.

Comment: Moreover, some of the information in `/etc/passwd` *must* be publicly readable: notable the connection between UID and username is established in that file.

Answer (score 1):

On linux the passwords are stored in /etc/shadow and on BSD systems they are stored in /etc/master.passwd.

Answer (score -1):

Storing passwords in /etc/password is sooo waay in the past. /etc/passwd is used for storing simple user information like UID, username, real name, etc. It also has a field that tells you if the account has a password, and if it does, you should look in /etc/passwd